# Write file in NodeJS with credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, fs

I am trying to write a file in nodejs and it is working fine using below code:

```
writeFile() {
        const sharedFolderPath = "\\server\folder";
        fs.writeFile(sharedFolderPath, templatePath, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.info("file created successfully");
            }
        })
    }
```

It is writing into the shared drive because I have permissions but I want to do it using superuser account but not getting how to inject superuser credentials?

The same above code failed if I am using with different user machine. Is there any way to write a file in NodeJS in shared folder using credentials?

Comment: `sudo your-file`

Comment: Why don't you make `\\server\folder` writeable by that other user? That would be the easiest.

Comment: The problem would be when we deploy this into paas like we are using Openshift and how to access this folder from there? So I though to write it with superuser credentials.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Windows and writing into a shared folder. The superuser in Windows is [`LOCAL_SYSTEM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx) but it only has superuser privileges on a local machine (otherwise a compromised `LOCAL_SYSTEM` could wreck havoc in your network). In other words, running an application as Administrator would not grant it privileges to bypass shared folder permissions.

The easiest solution would be to make that shared directory writable by the users you intend to run this application under.

Comment: But how the deployment works in that case? When we deploy the above code without any credentials then how the paas will setup a connection with the folder and write the content?

Comment: @user7890278 I am not familiar with paas, but each process runs under credentials of a specific user. Grant that user write privileges to that folder.